# can't deploy a scene with the SDK from the CLI

Tags: decentraland

Hi i can't deploy a scene with the DCL SDK, when i run "dcl deploy [my project]" it ask me to log, to say yes and thats ok but at the end it appear an error "✖ Failed to upload content
Error: `dcl deploy` Unable ro upload content. Invalid  Content-type: application/vnd.unity File: garden/@/artifacts/unity/Build/unity.wasm.code.unityweb, run".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you're getting, it looks like your project folder includes files that aren't compatible and can't be deployed, maybe something with an extension `.unity`

There are two possible solutions:

- Delete or move the files, so that they're no longer in the project folder
- Edit the .dclignore file, to tell the deploy to ignore files of that kind of extension when deploying

When deploying, you're uploading ALL of the content in the project folder, except the files that are signaled out by the .dclignore file.  If you're familiar with .gitignore, the concept is quite similar.